# How can I add tooltip to fullcalander

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I cannot get the different events in this calender to display a tooltip, can anyone show me how to do this?

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      schedulerLicenseKey: '0414383191-fcs-1575447448',
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'resourceTimeline' ],
      now: '2019-08-07',
      editable: false, // enable draggable events
      aspectRatio: 1.8,
      scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
      header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,timeline3Months'
      },
      defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
      views: {
        resourceTimelineThreeDays: {
          type: 'resourceTimeline',
          duration: { days: 3 },
          buttonText: '3 days'
        }
      },
      resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
      resources: [
        { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
        { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
        { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
        { id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D', children: [
          { id: 'd1', title: 'Room D1' },
          { id: 'd2', title: 'Room D2' }
        ] },
        { id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E' },
        { id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', eventColor: 'red' },
        { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G' },
        { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H' },
        { id: 'i', title: 'Auditorium I' },
        { id: 'j', title: 'Auditorium J' },
        { id: 'k', title: 'Auditorium K' },
        { id: 'l', title: 'Auditorium L' },
        { id: 'm', title: 'Auditorium M' },
        { id: 'n', title: 'Auditorium N' },
        { id: 'o', title: 'Auditorium O' },
        { id: 'p', title: 'Auditorium P' },
        { id: 'q', title: 'Auditorium Q' },
        { id: 'r', title: 'Auditorium R' },
        { id: 's', title: 'Auditorium S' },
        { id: 't', title: 'Auditorium T' },
        { id: 'u', title: 'Auditorium U' },
        { id: 'v', title: 'Auditorium V' },
        { id: 'w', title: 'Auditorium W' },
        { id: 'x', title: 'Auditorium X' },
        { id: 'y', title: 'Auditorium Y' },
        { id: 'z', title: 'Auditorium Z' }
      ],

      eventRender: function(info) {
        var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
          title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
          placement: 'top',
          trigger: 'hover',
          container: 'body'
        });
      },      

      events: [
        { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2019-08-07T02:00:00', end: '2019-08-07T07:00:00', title: 'event 1',description: 'description for event 1' },
        { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2019-08-07T05:00:00', end: '2019-08-07T22:00:00', title: 'event 2',description: 'description for event 2' },
        { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2019-08-06', end: '2019-08-08', title: 'event 3',description: 'description for event 3' },
        { id: '4', resourceId: 'e', start: '2019-08-07T03:00:00', end: '2019-08-07T08:00:00', title: 'event 4',description: 'description for event 4' },
        { id: '5', resourceId: 'f', start: '2019-08-07T00:30:00', end: '2019-08-07T02:30:00', title: 'event 5',description: 'description for event 5' }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
  });
```

If I remove the eventrender function, the calander is displayed but without tooltips. If I run the the calander as it is now nothing is displayed at all. I took the eventrender part from fullcalanders example but maybe its supposed to be added someplace else in function in order to get it to work. But I dont know where in that case...

Comment: "nothing id displayed at all"...probably you have a JavaScript error, did you check? If you're using these tooltips please ensure that you included popper.js and tooltip.js in yuor page, and that you also create some CSS to style the tooltips (if you go to the fullCalendar tooltip demo at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo and then click on the CodePen link (top-right of the screen) it contains some sample CSS you can use. You can also compare your code to the demo code and ensure everything else is in the right place (your eventRender placement is fine, by the way).

Comment: Yes I get 2 errors. Tooltip is not defined and Cannot read property 'style' But I dont know how to fix that...

Comment: "Tooltip is not defined" means you didn't include the tooltip.js file in your page. You also need popper.js These are separate files, not part of fullCalendar. Look at the CodePen demo and take note of which external files are included in that setup. (P.S. And I expect the second error is probably a symptom of the first, so please fix the Tooltip error to begin with).